Contact Form Details are not reciving to my outlook mails ,i have used phpmailer
i have created a form in my contact page , where people going to fill the basic details and when they hit submit all the details should be send to my outlook mail , i have used phpmailer for this. everything is fine but i dont know why they are not coming , please check the code below and let me know , thankyou.
<?php
  require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    
    $body = "
      <h3>Get in touch Form Data</h3> <br>
      Your Name * = $name; <br>
      Your Email * = $email; <br>
      Your Subject * = $subject; <br>
      Phone Number = $phone; <br>
      Your Text = $text; <br>
    ";

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //smtp settings
    $mail->IsSMTP();   
      $mail->isHTML(true);  
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                 
    $mail->Port       = 587;                    
    $mail->Host       = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"; 
      $mail->WordWrap     = 50;
    $mail->Username   = "name@domain.co.uk";   
    $mail->Password   = "password";
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
      $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $mail->IsSendmail();
    $mail->From       = "name@domain.co.uk";
    $mail->FromName   = "Get in touch Form Data";
    //email settings
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    // $mail->setFrom($email);
    $mail->addAddress("name@domain.co.uk");
    $mail->Subject = ("Get in touch Form Data");
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body);

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
      echo "Mail Not Sent";
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("Thank You Contacting Us We Will Response You As Early Possible")';
      echo '</script>';
  
    } 
}

?>

<form action="contact.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
                  <label class="form-label">
                    Your name
                    <span class="text-danger-alt">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class=" input-group form">
                    <input class="form-control " type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your full name">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
                  <label class="form-label">
                    Your email
                    <span class="text-danger-alt">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class=" input-group form">
                    <input class="form-control " type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
                  <label class="form-label">
                    Your subject
                  </label>
                  <div class=" input-group form">
                    <input class="form-control " type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
                  <label class="form-label">
                    Your phone
                  </label>
                  <div class="input-group form">
                    <input class="form-control " type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                  <label class="form-label">
                    Your message
                    <span class="text-danger-alt">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class=" input-group form mb-5">
                    <textarea class="form-control " rows="6" name="text" placeholder="Type your message"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-wide">Send Message</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>



Try removing the call to isSendmail

Here's the solved version of your PHP code


Added require for PHPMailer.php and SMTP.php
Cleaned up code structure


<?php
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $phone = isset($_POST['phone']) ? $_POST['phone'] : ''; // Handling phone field if it's not provided
        $text = $_POST['text'];
        
        $body = "
          <h3>Get in touch Form Data</h3> <br>
          Your Name * = $name; <br>
          Your Email * = $email; <br>
          Your Subject * = $subject; <br>
          Phone Number = $phone; <br>
          Your Text = $text; <br>
        ";
    
        $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    
        // SMTP settings
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host       = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Username   = "name@domain.co.uk";
        $mail->Password   = "password";
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0; // Set to 0 for production
    
        $mail->setFrom('name@domain.co.uk', 'Get in touch Form Data');
        $mail->addAddress("name@domain.co.uk");
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Get in touch Form Data";
        $mail->Body = $body;
    
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mail Not Sent";
        } else {
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Thank You for Contacting Us! We Will Respond to You As Early As Possible.")';
            echo '</script>';
        } 
    }
    ?>

<form action="contact.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
            <label class="form-label">
                Your name
                <span class="text-danger-alt">*</span>
            </label>
            <div class="input-group form">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your full name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
            <label class="form-label">
                Your email
                <span class="text-danger-alt">*</span>
            </label>
            <div class="input-group form">
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
            <label class="form-label">
                Your subject
            </label>
            <div class="input-group form">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-5">
            <label class="form-label">
                Your phone
            </label>
            <div class="input-group form">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <label class="form-label">
                Your message
                <span class="text-danger-alt">*</span>
            </label>
            <div class="input-group form mb-5">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" name="text" placeholder="Type your message" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-wide">Send Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

